# Class Form Alignment CSS

Tags: css, forms

I have come across a dynamically written form which I would like to style but I am unsure how to style this style of html -> Just as I was getting use to forms!

```
<pre wrap="">
<form action="http://develop.jzm.co.nz/pyrocms/contact" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="" class="name" />
    Email:<input type="text" name="email" value="" class="email" />
    Message:<textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10" class="message"></textarea>

<p class="contact-button"><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send"  /></p>
</form></pre>
```

Comment: @Arif Just needs general right alignment of the input boxes

Comment: I'm not sure why you need it in `<pre>` tags. Other than that, you can style the form however you want. Can you be more specific as to what you want to style, and what you want to do with it?

Comment: @JamWaffles That code is dynamically generated and I can't seem to add an id into the tag system I have tried form input but it does not seem to take

Comment: Can you dynamically add a div tag with a class in it that formats all these pieces of code the way you want?

Comment: @MikeDukeHall I have just clicked that the pre tags were added in by the wyiswyg so your idea should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten it was controlled by a WYSIWYG and the `pre` tags were added in when I saved I just changed them to a `<div id=""></div>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do. But i seem to be able to select them just fine  with `form input { }` and `form textarea { }`

here it is on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GRWZG/69/

you may be having some issues styling them if there is an already existing stylesheet that is overriding your styles